# Search Documents from two collections in MarkLogic

Tags: search, marklogic, cts

In Marklogic, I want to search between two collections by joining the id element of doc from collection1 to id element of doc from collection2. When it is matched i need the resulting document from both collections. 
I have the below code, but it is very slow. How to use cts:search or search:search to achieve the same

```
for $i in collection('demographic')/individual,
    $j in collection('membership')/membership[enrolleIndividualId/id/text() = $i/individual/id/text()])  
return {$i,$j}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update**:

I should note that your sample is not valid XQuery: `return element root { $i, $j }` would be valid. Also, you should not use the `/text()` node selector, as it's behavior can be counterintuitive. You can compare elements directly in an XPath predicate (`[enrolleIndividualId/id eq $i/individual/id]`). Use `/fn:string()` in place of `/text()` if you need the contents of an element as a string. I'd also recommend using the atomic equality operator `eq` in place of the sequence equality operator `=` when directly comparing individual elements.

*Original Answer:*

There are several approaches to implementing joins in MarkLogic, but I would first question your data model. From the names of the elements in your sample query, it looks like you are using a relational model (`individuals` have `memberships`). MarkLogic is a document database, and it's optimized for denormalized documents. You will be much better served to process your data and generate new `individual` documents that each contain the relevant `membership` data.

That being said, here's how you could join your documents:

First, you will need range indices to write performant joins. If the `id` element from your sample query is not unique to individuals, you will need path range indices on `enrolledIndividualId/id` and `individual/id`, otherwise, a simple element range index on `id` will do.

The most common join pattern in MarkLogic uses a "shotgun-OR" query; first retrieving values from the lexicon backing a range index, and then constructing an or-query from those values to retrieve the relevant documents. This won't work directly in your case, as you want to retrieve both sides of the join. You can either run a search for each pair of documents, or run a single search for one side, and then an additional document read for each document.

pairs:

```
for $value in cts:values(cts:path-reference("individual/id"))
return
  cts:search(/,
    cts:or-query((
      cts:and-query((
        cts:collection-query("demographic"),
        cts:path-range-query("individual/id", "=", $value))),
      cts:and-query((
        cts:collection-query("membership"),
        cts:path-range-query("enrolledIndividualId/id", "=", $value))))),
    "unfiltered")
```

shotgun-OR plus iteration:

```
for $doc in 
  cts:search(/,
    cts:and-query((
      cts:collection-query("demographic"),
      cts:path-range-query("individual/id", "=",
        cts:values(cts:path-reference("individual/id"))))),
    "unfiltered")
return
  cts:search(/,
    cts:and-query((
      cts:collection-query("membership"),
      cts:path-range-query("enrolledIndividualId/id", "=", $doc/individual/id))),
    "unfiltered")
```

As you can see, each approach requires I/O proportionate to the number of docs/values you want to join. If you only needed the shotgun-OR (ie, a query for documents based on criteria from other documents), you would only need to make two requests, the initial `cts:values()` call to retrieve values from a lexicon, and the `cts:search()` call using a query built from those values.

Note: the `cts:query` objects used in these examples could be used in conjunction with the Search API by means of the `search:resolve()` function.

Given your apparent data model, you will be much better served by processing your data into individual, de-normalized documents.